# Paragraph not responding to changes when assigned class name

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to adjust one paragraph of two in the same div, I'm not sure how to do this but I tried to give one of the paragraphs a class, as a result they both started to respond on just p without any unique name. I'm not sure why or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Css:

```
.col_12 p1{margin-left:240px; position:relative;}
```

Html:

```
<div class="col_12">
<h3>Contact</h3>
<p><?php show_post('contact'); ?></p>
    <p class="p1"><div id="map_canvas"></div></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me a `<div>` won't be allowed inside a `<p>`.
You may use a `<span>` instead.

-Sven

Comment: Found out about it before I checked back here but yes this is the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
.col_12 p1{margin-left:240px; position:relative;}
```

won't work because you missing a `.` before `p1`

your css should be:

```
.col_12 .p1{margin-left:240px; position:relative;}
```

Comment: I completely agree with you, thanks! But it still isn't budging. The strange thing is that when I assign the div map canvas to h3 instead of a paragraph(For example) and change the .col_12 p1 to .col_12 h3 it does respond, I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax not correct , You need to put `.` before class name of paragraph tag

```
.col_12 .p1{margin-left:240px; position:relative;}
________^__________________________________________
```

Comment: That's what I thought but it didn't help it seems, check out what I responded to donnywals.

Comment: I just now saw in my the inspect element, that <p> doesn't wrap the map canvas but <h3> does? It just feels incorrect wrapping an image in a heading..

Comment: I don't understand it anymore, in the inspect element nothing but a heading wraps the div, the paragraph just opens and closes off before the div starts and then after the div a random other paragraph appears that opens and closes itself too! So I suppose the issue lies in html but what..

Comment: i think you are correct, personally i wouldnt put <p> around a <div> it is redundancy, just put divs

Comment: looks like your class `map_canvas` or the default style for `div` is overriding/masking the style of the class `p1`

Answer (score 0):

this should work more dynamically

```
   .col_12 p:nth-child(2){margin-left:240px; position:relative;}
```

Comment: Not working :S (I'm on wordpress if that's the issue?)

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can try with your own class like this 
 `.col_12 p1{margin-left:240px !important; position:relative;}`